# New component is placed in the middle instead below another one in Vaadin VerticalLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have problem with sidebar menu in Vaadin, I have navigation bar that is 50px height. I wish to place sidebar (at this moment just VerticalLayout with buttons) that gonna take rest of the screen. The problem is when I add my sidebar to main layout it start from middle of the screen, 
[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jctVl.png)

I tried to use

```
setSizeFull();
```

method on my main layout but then it looks [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XB7K.png) (even when I set my sidebar height to 100%)

There is code behind my sidebar:

public class Sidebar {

```
private VerticalLayout sidebar;
private Button menuItem01;
private Button menuItem02 = new Button("Item02");

//Create Sidebar
public VerticalLayout initSidebar() {
    sidebar = new VerticalLayout();
    sidebar.setWidth("10%");
    sidebar.setHeight("100%");
    sidebar.setMargin(false);
    sidebar.addComponent(createMenuItem());
    sidebar.addComponent(menuItem02);
    sidebar.addStyleName("sidebar");
    return sidebar;
}

public Button createMenuItem(){
    menuItem01 = new Button("Item01");
    return menuItem01;
}
```

}

And there is code behind my MainView

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    template.setMargin(false);
    template.setSpacing(false);
    //template.setSizeFull();

    //Place all elements together
    template.addComponent(navigationBar.initNavigationBar());
    //template.addComponent(mainContent.initMainPanel());
    template.addComponent(sidebar.initSidebar());

    this.setContent(template);
}
```

Finally Navbar if needed:

public class NavigationBar {

```
private HorizontalLayout navbar;
private Button hamburgerButton;
private Label logo;

//Create Navigation Bar
public HorizontalLayout initNavigationBar() {
    navbar = new HorizontalLayout();
    navbar.setWidth("100%");
    navbar.setMargin(true);
    navbar.setHeight(50, Sizeable.Unit.PIXELS);
    navbar.addComponent(createHamburgerButton());
    navbar.addComponent(createLogo());
    navbar.addStyleName("navigation-bar");
    return navbar;
}

//Create Hamburger Button
public Button createHamburgerButton() {
    hamburgerButton = new Button();

    //Added some styling to hamburger button
    hamburgerButton.addStyleName("hamburger-button");
    hamburgerButton.setIcon(VaadinIcons.MENU);

    return hamburgerButton;
}

//Create ElenX logo
public Label createLogo() {
    logo = new Label("ElenX");
    logo.addStyleName("elenx-logo");
    logo.setWidthUndefined();
    logo.setEnabled(false);
    return logo;
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `VerticalLayout` has a height of 100% it will share the space with all contained components equally, unless you set expand ratios.  You can tell the vertical layout to give all room to one component via `verticalLayout.setExpandRatio(secondComponent, 1.0f)`.  That will collapse your first component to just the room it needs and give the second one everything from the first to the bottom.

Comment: template.addComponent(sidebar.initSidebar());
        template.setExpandRatio(sidebar.initSidebar(), 1.0f);

Comment: I jsut got The given component is not a child of this layout error

Comment: why do you call "initSidebar" twice?

Comment: ok i fixed that. But what if I want to place elements just below each other? without his weird spacing? Like 4x 50px height buttons